# String Replacing All Characters Not Working JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am very new to JS, but very good with PHP. It is a tough transition!
Now to the problem, live replacing characters in a string.

Basically I have a textarea, and I would like to live update all of its contents to the div below. Then on top of that for each live update I would like to replace all '[' and ']' with '<' and '>', and it gets a little bit more complex. I would like it to display as live HTML (sense they will be HTML tags from BBCode).

This is currently what I have:

HTML -

```
<textarea id="my_textarea" name="my_textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="b" name="texteditorstylebuttonbold"/>
<input type="button" value="i" name="texteditorstylebuttonitalicize"/>
<input type="button" value="u" name="texteditorstylebuttonunderline"/>
<div id="display"></div>
```

JS -

```
function getInputSelection(elem){
    if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
        start = elem[0].selectionStart;
        end = elem[0].selectionEnd;
        return elem.val().substring(start, end);
    }
    else{
        return '';
    }
}

$('input:button[name^="texteditorstylebutton"]').click(function() {
    var myTextAreaValue = $('#my_textarea').val();
    var selectedText = getInputSelection($('#my_textarea'));
    var updatedText = '['+$(this).val()+']' + selectedText + '[/'+$(this).val()+']';
    myTextAreaValue = myTextAreaValue.replace(selectedText, updatedText);
    $('#my_textarea').val(myTextAreaValue)
});

$('my_textarea').onkeyup(function() {
    $('display').val() = $('#my_textarea').val().replace(new RegExp("[", 'g'), "<");
});
```

Before I continue, the other code, and inputs, are used to make style buttons for the code, and they are suppose to be BBCode. I know that is not fully what BBCode actually is, but I am making my own type of thing! :) The problem is though that this code will not even live update the code... Please Help!

P.S. A little example:

User enters this in the text area: `[b] This is bold text [/b]`

Then live, it will replace the [b] with a bold HTML tag and show this to the user down below: **This is bold text**

Please just ask if you do not understand what the problem is. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2 ~ *"This method is typically used to set the values of **form fields**."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you want to append some html content to the div. If you want your div to recognize the html tags, you need to use `.html()` property:

```
$('#display').html($('#my_textarea').val());
```

Also, you need to update this part as follows (`onkeyup` should be `keyup` and please do not forget to include `#` if you are using **ID SELECTER**):

```
$('#my_textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('#display').html($('#my_textarea').val());
});
```

Here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0uoshu0s/6/

Comment: I'd even go so far as to use `#display`

Comment: So what you are saying is use that for the part that prints to the new div? Currently no text will even print to the div :(

Comment: if you are still using `$('display').val() =` yes it will not, it should have been `$('display').val('new value')` did you try what I posted?

Comment: Here is the code I am currently using: `$('#my_textarea').onkeyup(function() {
 $('#display').html($('#my_textarea').val());
});`

Comment: we need a jsfiddle :)

Comment: @MichaelJones see the update, I removed RegEx part since It was causing trouble. you need to take care of that part.

Comment: Thank You! :) You are the best, I just need something to work off when first learning. I will get the next part. Thank you though! :D You are so helpful today!!!! :)

Comment: @MichaelJones I have been helping you for several days, it is pleasure! :)

Comment: Oh, well thank you for all of the days! :) It is so surprising how different coding languages are. Python was easier to learn, PHP very easy, JS not so much! xD

Comment: $erkaner, Just incase you are curious, here is the code that transfers the code from 'BBCode' to HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/0uoshu0s/7/

Comment: @MichaelJones thanks for sharing, I like `.split('[').join('<')`